# How to know Spring Boot starting errors in details in console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that this is a very trivial question but please suggest me to find the way. Sometimes when I start Spring Boot server, it stops but it does not display the complete error/exception stack trace. Think of situation that spring boot server has been started in 8080 port and if somebody starts in 8080 port, it should clearly display that java.net.BindException. But in my case server simply aborts.
I normally find the issue from the IDE like eclipse/Idea when I start the server in debug mode. But how to **find the error when somebody starts spring boot server using command prompt** ? There may be many errors for which spring boot is unable to start. **My question is what configurations should be added in application.properties to know more details about the error/s for which spring boot is not getting started**. Currently I am using **Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE** version. Please help me fix this.

Comment: try cleaning local repo, that should might be libraries issue

Answer (score 1):

To see more details of the actions being carried out for a spring boot application, change the log level to debug. You can do it just by simply adding below lines in application.property/yaml file.

```
logging.level.=DEBUG
```

Or for web applications you can try

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

Comment: Before posting this question, I had already tried this options. It does not work. Do a small litmus test, start the spring boot server in 8080 port, once it starts running, open command prompt and start once again. You won't see any error, it simply exits.

Comment: Are you writing the logs to any file? If so, check the log file, otherwise write the logs to a file and check it.

Comment: I have verified the log file, there is no entry.

Comment: try running the app with TRACE level logs by providing the vm argument 
-Dlogging.level.org.springframework=TRACE

Answer (score 0):

Add the below property in application.xml - worked in Spring boot 2.2.4

> logging.level.root:ERROR